# Google App Script to rename a downloaded file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

please assist. 
I have a Google App Script that downloads an Excel file from the internet into my Google Drive. This is working. Thereafter the file needs to be renamed, this I'm struggling with.

Downloading of file working. Struggling with renaming...

```
function SaveToGoogleDrive()

  var folderID = 'foldername';  // put id of the Google Drive folder
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID) // get the folder
  var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch("thewebsite");
  folder.createFile(file);
  //file.remame("NewDownloadedFile); // help? 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function SaveToGoogleDrive()
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderID');
  var fileblob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("thewebsite").getBlob();
  var file=folder.createFile(fileblob);
  file.setName('NewDownLoadFile');
}
```